# How do I create Admin module for registered users in MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on an MVC webapp and am done with the registration module that uses the SQL Membership tables.

Now, I have written code that, when a user gets created and is approved, the application sends an email to the user with an activation link in email.

Now I want to create an admin page where admin can approve those registered users

How can I do this?

code:

```
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Attempt to register the user
        MembershipCreateStatus createStatus = MembershipService.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email);

        if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
        {
            // FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);

            //used profiler  -- add profile information
            var profile = Profile.GetProfile(model.UserName);
            profile.FirstName = model.FirstName;
            profile.LastName = model.LastName;
            profile.Save();

            //email confirmation code
            MembershipService.SendConfirmationEmail(model.UserName);
            return RedirectToAction("Confirmation");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", AccountValidation.ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    ViewData["PasswordLength"] = MembershipService.MinPasswordLength;
    return View(model);
}

//send confirmation code
public void SendConfirmationEmail(string userName)
{
    MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(userName);
    string confirmationGuid = user.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
    string verifyUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) +
                     "/account/verify?ID=" + confirmationGuid;

    var message = new MailMessage("contacts@abc.com", user.Email)
    {
        Subject = "Please confirm your email",
        Body = verifyUrl

    };

    var client = new SmtpClient();

    client.Send(message);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to look into [configuring an Area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) for your site.

From the link:

> To accommodate large projects, ASP.NET MVC lets you partition Web
>   applications into smaller units that are referred to as areas. Areas
>   provide a way to separate a large MVC Web application into smaller
>   functional groupings. An area is effectively an MVC structure inside
>   an application. An application could contain several MVC structures
>   (areas).
>
> For example, a single large e-commerce application might be divided
>   into areas that represent the storefront, product reviews, user
>   account administration, and the purchasing system. Each area
>   represents a separate function of the overall application.

Comment: To add to Jasons comment, I encourage areas for this task as well. You'll need to build a set of controllers, views and possibly models to support your Admin area. Since you're using a membership provider you should decorate your controllers or your controller actions with Authorize filters to allow only admins access to the area.